# The most optimal way : str_replace, nested replace

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have a question, what is the most optimal way for replace the strings for example, I want to replace \n and \r\n with ''.
I have 2 options :

1. Replaces nested:

   `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(m3.old_message,'\n',''),'\r\n','')`
2. Preg replace:

   `if ($aField== 'user') {
       $sValue = preg_replace...
     }`

Thx in advance.

Comment: Both ways can be optimal. Before finding the optimal way you should have a benchmark mechanism. Firstly find your execution bottleneck(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Bottlenecks).

Comment: Why won't u check your methods on test data similiar to one you are using?

Comment: probably your 'outer' replace will never fire, as \n is already replaced there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can do:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\R/', '.', $string);
```

Where `\R`  stands for any line break, `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`.